# How to use Sql server compact toolbox in visual studio 2015 - Asp.net core project

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using visual studio 2015(asp.net core project).In my project I have created a database using server compact tool box. When I try to generate code to add entity data model to the current project the following error occurs: "Please add the Entity Framework.SqlserverCompact Nuget package to the project". I have added the package from Nuget package manager as follows. - Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. Also I tried to add by manage nuget packages. Even then the same error occurs. Please let me know how to resolve this issue in asp.net core. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you should display this package [EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/) as you want to use SqlServer Compact edition. You are installing this [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) which is for the full feature Sql Server.

Remove the one you've installed and thy the one that error message suggests.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I have tried the one which is suggested by Nuget package,but still the same error occurs.

Comment: @shivani did you remove the old package and keep only the SqlServerCompact? Did you check if SQL CE supports Asp.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the PMC command

Scaffold-DbContext

As described here to create a model from a database: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/wiki/Using-EF-Core-with-SQL-Server-Compact-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications